# Why am I getting odd inductances from home made inductor?

Tags: inductor, measurement, planar-inductor

This question is related my my previous question: [What to do about very hot planar inductor?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/201300/what-to-do-about-very-hot-planar-inductor)

**What I'm trying to do**

I am trying to make a planar inductor (made from the tracks of the PCB, and surrounded by a 2 part a ferrite core). According to the [datasheet](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1899620.pdf) of the ferrite core, the AL value is 1700nH, which means that with 12 turns around the core, I should get 12x12x1.7 = 244uH.

**The problem**

However, when I measure the inductance on my LC meter, it reads only 1.8uH. What's stranger is that if I create an inductor with the same core, but using stranded wire, and only 10 turns, I get 46uH!

I measured the resistance of the PCB tracks, and it's 0.25R, just as it should be, so I don't think there's a short in there.

[image: Planar vs wound inductor]

[image: Planar inductor layers]

**My questions**

What's going on? Is the AL value not sufficient for calculating inductance? How could it be that fewer turns gives a *much* higher inductance? Is the stranded wire massively better than PCB trace?

Comment: 1 shorted turn will do this. Please show all the layers seperately - I can see what technique you have used and it looks sound so the devil must be in the detail. I've made them myself and not had a problem so there isn't something innately flaky about this methodology. How does light blue connect to dark blue?

Comment: Measure the layers independently and then assembled, chances are that there is some short or direction change or ao

Comment: It looks like your layers are spiraling in then spiraling out. Can you confirm that? If so, you're changing the direction and cancelling the inductance.

Comment: @Samuel they look OK to me!

Comment: @Andyaka - I've added the image showing the layers.

Comment: How tight are the core halves fitting? Is it possible that stray glass fibre or other mechanical problems are introducing air gaps? (And a much smaller airgap in the hand-wound one?) NB Sticky tape won't do it... there are usually strong spring clips or similar to ensure consistent clamping.

Comment: the slightest gap between mating faces of the core will collapse the inductance value. Are you sure the faces are meeting, and not being fouled by the PCB?

Comment: Yeah they look cool and exactly how I did it on a regular transformer. Shorted turn is my guess.

Comment: @Andy : apropos of which : that white stuff inside the hole isn't through-hole plating, I hope!

Comment: perhaps there is much more parasitic capacitance between the PCB layers than there is between your insulated wires. I don't have a gut feeling for this, but it might be something to look into. To test this, maybe you could try separating the PCB layers a little bit in an attempt to reduce the parasitic capacitance between layers.

Comment: @BrianDrummond - I've tried pressing the halves tightly together with my fingers. The PCB is 1.6mm thick, and the cores have about 3.5mm space inside. The inside of the hole is plated, but that plating isn't connected to the coil (I already checked that).

Comment: @Andyaka - If a shorted turn is the problem, then why is 10 turns of stranded wire producing only 46uH, when I calculate that it should produce 170uH. Am I calculating it wrong?

Comment: @BrianDrummond - I disagree about the air gap. Using [this document](http://coefs.uncc.edu/mnoras/files/2013/03/Transformer-and-Inductor-Design-Handbook_Chapter_8.pdf) I calculated the expected inductance including a 0.1mm gap, and it still comes out at about 244uH.

Comment: Could it be that the formulas you use are for when the core material is inside the windings?

Comment: If the inside of the hole is plated, there's your shorted turn. Get the scalpel out! Doesn't matter if it's electrically isolated, it's still tightly coupled via the core. So you're measuring the leakage inductance at 1.8 uH.

Comment: I think @BrianDrummond nailed it. Whether internal holes are plated or not seems to be a bit of a crap shoot. Some use copper on either side of the edges as a marker for 'should be plated', but you have a definite gap there. All you need to do is to break the plating at one spot so it isn't a complete turn.

Comment: @BrianDrummond GOOD SHOUT DUDE.

Comment: @Rocketmagnet - how did you measure the inductance?

Comment: @OlinLathrop - I have to admit I was surprised at the calculation of 244uH. In that case, can you explain the AL value of 1700nH, and why is the calculation 12x12x1.7uH wrong?

Comment: @Andyaka - I used a little LC meter I got from eBay. I checked it against some known inductances of similar values, and it seemed to be accurate.

Comment: @Rocketmagnet conceivably it may have a drive level that is actually saturating the core and thus reducing the inductance.

Comment: @Andyaka - I considered that, but it the core doesn't get even slightly warm during the measurement.

Comment: @OlinLathrop - I removed the plating as Brian suggested, and measured 280uH. So I guess it is possible to get hundreds of uH in such a small inductor.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Brian has nailed it. Good shout. @Brian please take this picture and make your own answer. I'll delete this answer as soon as: -

[image]

### NO VOTES PLEASE

Comment: No, shorted turn was your suggestion in the first place. (Upvoted) And I'm expecting there'll still be some discrepancy as with the hand winding, (gap?) so we may not be quite done yet.

Comment: @BrianDrummond You are a gentleman. Looking at the data sheet tells us that N97 material in that core size is indeed 1800nH for 1 turn so that's looking suspiciously significant. Using the wire should produce 180uH but it all depends on the measurement method - if it's being overdriven then saturation could easily decimate that inductance.

Comment: Fits well with his original question where he wondered why that thing got hot

Comment: You could always mark it as community wiki instead of "no votes please"... that way it can be upvoted (as it should because it's the correct answer)... but since you want Brian to [rightfully] get the credit.

Comment: @RespawnedFluff how does one do that?

Comment: Click edit and there's a checkbox for community wiki right under the edit window (above preview); it's on the right-hand side. Not the easiest thing to find usability wise, if you ask me.

Comment: Is there some explanation about what community wiki means or implies? I can't deny that I've seen it but I can't deny (to myself) that I have any idea what it means. Help me out here stack exchange!

Comment: That's genius! So obvious now. Damn, I wish it wasn't the weekend so I could go and try it.

Comment: @BrianDrummond - OK, drilled out the plating, and re-measured it at 280uH!

Comment: That's a good result but, going back to your original question, does the Damn thing now work as a switcher? You may still have too much magnetization inductance and start to hit problems delivering the power on fuller loads.

Answer (score 0):

If the stack height of your pcbs is such that the core is not completely mated then this will dramatically lower your inductance.

Comment: The single PCB here is 1.6mm, whereas there's 3.5mm of space inside the cores.